# Pynput: input out of command line

Tags: python, macos, pynput

I am trying to write a python3 script using pynput which presses a key in order to automate a repetitive task I have to do. The code is the following:

```
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

keyboard.press(Key.enter)
keyboard.release(Key.enter)
# Press and release space
while True:
    keyboard.press(Key.space)
    keyboard.release(Key.space)
    time.sleep(1)
```

My problem is that it works, but only in command line. I don't have any idea how to export the input to the open window with the task I have to perform. I am using an OsX system. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the task part of an application? Is it a file system task? Is it reading data from a file? Can you be more descriptive about what you are trying to accomplish? All we know is the code works in console.

Comment: I am working on a mod of a game which is emulated in openemu and I need to press the same key for many times in an openemu window, so it is part of an application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only works in console because the keystrokes are staying within the python environment. To interact with an application you need to use your OS. Do this in python using `os.system()`. Since your script is run from console you will need to first switch to your target application.

Simulate Alt+Tab:

```
os.system('\nosascript -e \'tell application "System Events" to key code 48 using {command down}\' \n')
```

You will need to add delays between your key-down and key-up commands because OpenEmu won't be able to detect key-up at the speed your script will execute.

This post has more information [Macbook OpenEmu Python send keystrokes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39671998/macbook-openemu-python-send-keystrokes)

Comment: I know is a stupid question, but I do not understand the ```key code 48 using {command down}``` part. I mean, why is it simulating alt+cmd? How can I simulate other key combos?

Comment: Thank you, in general your solution is the most optimal I found, even if it turned out that OpenEmu doesn't support AppleScript, but only a quite obscure third party script language, so I had to give up. For any other tasks I think this solution is good.

Comment: Command is Apple's version of alt. Key code 48 is for tab. My example uses python to tell the OS to switch windows. Here is a list of AppleScript keyboard commands https://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes

Here's another helpful resource http://macbiblioblog.blogspot.com/2014/12/key-codes-for-function-and-special-keys.html